# RxJava timeout without emiting error?

Tags: operators, rx-java

Is there an option to have variant of `timeout` that does not emit `Throwable`?

I would like to have `complete` event emited.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can resume from an error with another `Observable`, for example :

```
 Observable<String> data = ...
 data.timeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
     .onErrorResumeNext(Observable.empty())
     .subscribe(...);
```

Comment: That's what this code do. It will transform your error to a Observable that will complete imediately

Comment: It's worth noting that this solution doesn't work if there's a possibility of errors coming from further upstream, because it'll catch those too...

Comment: downvote - this will cause all other valid errors to return empty

Answer (score 23):

You don't need to map errors with onErrorResumeNext. You can just provide a backup observable using:

[timeout(long,TimeUnit,Observable)](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#timeout-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-rx.Observable-)

It would be something like:

```
    .timeout(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, Observable.empty())
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer because the original post is asking for a variant of 'timeout', which this answer provides.

Answer (score 11):

A simpler solution that does not use `Observable.timeout` (thus it does not generate an error with the risk of catching unwanted exceptions) might be to simply take until a timer completes:

```
Observable<String> data = ...
data.takeUntil(Observable.timer(1, TimeUnit.SECOND))
    .subscribe(...);
```

Comment: But `timer` here is not restarted every time the source `Observable` emits an item, in contrast to `timeout`.

Answer (score 4):

You can always use **onErrorResumeNext** which will get the error and you can emit whatever item you want-

```
    /**
 * Here we can see how onErrorResumeNext works and emit an item in case that an error occur in the pipeline and an exception is propagated
 */
@Test
public void observableOnErrorResumeNext() {
    Subscription subscription = Observable.just(null)
                                          .map(Object::toString)
                                          .doOnError(failure -> System.out.println("Error:" + failure.getCause()))
                                          .retryWhen(errors -> errors.doOnNext(o -> count++)
                                                                     .flatMap(t -> count > 3 ? Observable.error(t) : Observable.just(null)),
                                                     Schedulers.newThread())
                                          .onErrorResumeNext(t -> {
                                              System.out.println("Error after all retries:" + t.getCause());
                                              return Observable.just("I save the world for extinction!");
                                          })
                                          .subscribe(s -> System.out.println(s));
    new TestSubscriber((Observer) subscription).awaitTerminalEvent(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```

Comment: I would like to complete stream after onError

Comment: you will, in onErrorResumenNext you will emit your Observable which it will finish the pipeline. Run the test that I wrote and you will understand. If you want to see more practical examples check here https://github.com/politrons/reactive